# c4d and python about mouse click

Tags: python, cinema-4d

I have tried to get the poly when mouse click. Does c4d have this method, actually I want to get the poly's normal, but the polyobject baseobject and sculpobject made me confused. Can poly object change to a sculpobject? Can anyone help me? How do I get the normal of a polygon of a base object? I am a beginner, please show me more detail or concept.

Comment: please include some code snippets to get faster response.

Comment: Welcome. Please read and following posting guidelines: [What kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), *please limit your question to a [specific issue]*https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), complete with a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot effectively help you until you post your code, or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem. **We should be able to paste your attempted code into a text file** to reproduce your specific issue.